# Calling an async function in Task.Run

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I use a waiting form with an animated gif inside.
The only way i've found to display this form with the animated gif "moving" is :

```
frmWaiting.Show()
Await Task.Run(Sub() AnyKindOfActionInASub)
frmWaiting.Close()
```

It works well but what if i need to call an async function returning an object instead of a simple sub? If i do :

```
Dim TwitterAccountToAdd As TwitterAccount
frmWaiting.Show()
TwitterAccountToAdd = Await nsTweetInvi.CallTwitterApi.GetApiTwitterDatasAccount(Me.txtTwitterId.Text)
frmWaiting.Close()
```

The animated gif is replaced by a white square.

Considering that GetApiTwitterDatasAccount return a *Task(Of TwitterAccount)*, how can i do this?

Comment: Not done much async personally, so just a comment, but I believe the trick is you still need to wrap your call in a task, then still await the task, and at the end check `Task.Result` to find the result of the function call.

Comment: You need to look at what `GetApiTwitterDatasAccount` is doing.  That's a perfectly cromulent thing to `Await` by the looks of it, but if it's doing anything substantial beyond waiting for a response from the remote host, that "anything" will be running on the UI thread and blocking your animation.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn your suggested sequence isn't any different from what is actually done here.  The actual difference is that the original code was using `Task.Run` which will schedule onto a thread pool thread.  `Task.Run` isn't really appropriate for waiting for I/O or network as the second does, but as I noted, if it's doing anything interesting beyond that waiting, the "anything interesting" will happen on the UI thread.

Comment: Is `GetApiTwitterDatasAccount` actually asynchronous? If it is, awaiting it will have the same effect as the code in the first snippet. Otherwise, you can `Task.Run()` it and await the results, as, well, in the first snippet. In that case it would be , e.g., `dim theText = Me.txtTwitterId.Text dim TwitterAccountToAdd = await Task.Run(Function() nsTweetInvi.CallTwitterApi.GetApiTwitterDatasAccount(theText))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Jimi advices, i found a solution that works perfectly.

```
Private TwitterAccountToAdd As New TwitterAccount
Dim strTwitterId As String = Me.txtTwitterId.Text
Dim frmWaitingTwitter As New frmWaiting
Me.TopMost = False
With frmWaitingTwitter
     .TopMost = True
     .Show()
     .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
End With
TwitterAccountToAdd = Await Task.Run(Function() CheckAndGetTwitterAccount(strTwitterId))
frmWaitingTwitter.Close()
Me.TopMost = True
```